# How to write concurrent REST requests counter

Tags: java, rest, synchronization, jmeter

I work on stress tests for REST server. 
My aim is to create a mock controller method, which will throw 404 Error every 100 requests (other results are 200 OK), and check the total amount of sent requests and failed ones.

The problem is, even though I use ConcurrentHashMap and AtomicInteger for counting those figures, the amount of failed request varies +-20. Synchronization of RequestCounter.addFailed() didn't help. The only way I found is to synchronize controller's method, but it's not the option.

I run 220_000 stress test requests with 20 threads via Jmeter. 
Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/items/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity addGDT(@RequestBody String data, Principal principal) {
    RequestCounter.add();
    if ((RequestCounter.getCounts().get("ADD").longValue() % 100) == 0) {
        RequestCounter.addFailed();
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

The number of requests is counted here:

```
public class RequestCounter {
static Map<String, AtomicInteger> counts = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
static {
    counts.put("ADD", new AtomicInteger(0));
    counts.put("ADD_FAILED", new AtomicInteger(0));
}

public static void add(){
    counts.get("ADD_GDT").incrementAndGet();
}

public static void addFailed(){
    counts.get("ADD_FAILED").incrementAndGet();
}
```

**UPDATE**
I followed an advice of javaguy and refactored the code by removing map and working with AtomicInteger variables directly. But the result is still unpredictable: failedRequestCount still varies from +-3

```
public class RequestCounter {
static AtomicInteger failedRequestsCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
...
public static void addGDTFailed(){
    failedRequestsCounter.incrementAndGet();
}
```

**UPDATE2**
The situation wasn't resolved neither by calling directly the thread-safe variable, nor by separation and synchronization of a method for getting modulus

Comment: you can have a look and let me know if my solution worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `RequestCounter` class is not `threadsafe` because of these two lines:

```
counts.get("ADD_GDT").incrementAndGet(); 
counts.get("ADD_FAILED").incrementAndGet();
```

These are NOT atomic operations i.e., actually, the computation involves two steps (read the value from Map and then write). Though `ConcurrentHashMap` and `AtomicInteger` are individually threadsafe, but when you use them collectively, you need a synchronization or locking.

But you can achieve what you wanted for your testing with a much simpler code without using a `ConcurrentHashMap` itself.

To make the `RequestCounter` class threadsafe, just remove the Map, and directly access the AtomicInteger reference as below:

```
public class RequestCounter {

        private final AtomicLong addInt = new AtomicLong();
        private final AtomicLong addFailed = new AtomicLong();

        public static long get() {
            return addInt.get();
        }

        public static long add() {
            return addInt.incrementAndGet();
        }

        public static long addFailed(){
            return addFailed.incrementAndGet();
        }
}
```

**UPDATE1: Problem with 3% variation of requests:**

You need to esnure that `RequestCounter.add()` is being called `only once per request`, look at my controller code below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/items/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity addGDT(@RequestBody String data, Principal principal) {

    if ((RequestCounter.get() % 100) == 0) {
        RequestCounter.addFailed();
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    } else {
        RequestCounter.add();
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought this issue could be solved by a simple synchronization of addFailed(), but the reality is vice verse. Could you please explain why

Comment: You can do synchronization, but it adds unnecessary cost (time) for each transaction.

Comment: You don't actually need a Map here

Comment: The result of code refactoring improves the situation, but not dramatically. Details are in the edited description of an issue

Comment: Check my code for Controller and added get() method inside RequestCounter() and changed to AtomicLong

Comment: This approach didn't work. I put RequestCounter.add(); before if(){} block, since I have to count the total number of request, not only success ones. Even though I synchronized condition block and simplified interaction with counter (removed map), result still varies